min_timesatamp and max_timestamp are not working in the trongridAPI
API reference: https://developers.tron.network/reference/get-transaction-info-by-account-address
Here is the HTTP request:
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'TRON-PRO-API-KEY':api_key
}
response = requests.get(f"https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/{address}/transactions?min_timestamp={min_timestamp}", headers=headers)

where min_timestamp:
min_timestamp="2024-11-01T04:30:00Z"

or
min_timestamp="1730558155"

Neither of them worked

any luck to figure this out? having same problem...

Use the timestamp in milliseconds, so
min_timestamp="1730558155000"  @Andrew

The timestamp should be provided in milliseconds, not mentioned in the docs
Example:
min_timestamp="1730558155000"

thanks a ton man! though I already implemented paginated approach, at least now I know how it's supposed to work :D seems like TronGrid is pretty big servise so they could mention this tiny detail in the docs for noobs like me :)

min_timestamp expects a UNIX timestamp in milliseconds (e.g., 1730558155000).
Ensure you are providing a valid timestamp in this format.
